# Hover Tiles SquareSpace Custom CSS

Tags: css, tile, least-squares

I am pretty new to CSS and I am trying to write some custom code for my squarespace site. Below is my current CSS and my site is http://www.sophieamberkar.com/. I am trying to create hover tiles over the existing 4 image tiles I have on my landing page. Currently I am just getting small rectangle that pops up at the bottom. [see image with blue rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w7WS.png) What I want to have happen is to have the blue rectangle cover the entire image on hover and reveal the text that is currently shown in the small blue rectangle.

I already tried increasing the hight and line height but it increases it below the actual image instead of on top of the image. Any help would be great!

```
.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper .image-slide-title {
 display:block;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
 position: relative;
 top: -15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: #1E75BB;
 margin-bottom: 0px; 
 }
 .sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper:hover .image-slide-title {
 display: block;
 opacity: 50; 
 background-color: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 }

  .sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper:hover .image-slide-title {
 font-family: adelle-sans;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: What I am trying to have occur is similar to this site https://jasper-demo.squarespace.com/

Comment: If the blue div covers the entire image the image will not be clickable because it's not a link

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with the following for the particular selector:

```
.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper .image-slide-title{
display:inline-block;
height:188px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-top:0;
}
```

With above code blue background will cover entire image area but the text inside the blue box will appear on top of the box. Change HTML and insure the text in  and style it in the center of the blue box.